# Region integral of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to evaluate the following integral

$$\int_R \exp\left({\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}}\right)\,\mathrm dA$$

with the boundary conditions:

$$\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}=2$$
$$\frac{x^2}{16}+\frac{y^2}{9}=4$$

It seems that polar coordinates of some kind could be helpful, but I'm not totally sure where to move from here. How would you setup this integral so as to actually complete it. It will obviously end up a double integral.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that

$$
\frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{y^2}{9} = r^2
$$

is the equation for ellipse:
$$
\frac{x^2}{16 r^2} + \frac{y^2}{9 r^2} = 1
$$

So the given integral is integrated over the region between two ellipses:
$\frac{x^2}{32} + \frac{y^2}{18} = 1$ and $\frac{x^2}{64} + \frac{y^2}{36} = 1$.
You can make the substitution below to convert this integral to integral in polar coordinates:
$$
\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
    x = 4r\cos{t} & \\
    y = 3r\sin{t} & \\
\end{array}
\right. 
(0 \leq t \leq 2\pi)
\end{equation}
$$

and you can verify that substitution above represents an ellipse.

Visualize the integral region:

[image: The integral region]

Comment: What would the $dr$ part of the double integral look like if you don't mind taking this one step further? I'm not sure whether I want to be integrating $e^{f(\theta)}$ from 2 to 5 or $e^{r^2}$ from $f_1(\theta)$ to $f_2(\theta)$